# Where clause as string in Find/FindOne TypeORM

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I was searching and reading the docs, but coundn't find a solution.

Is there a way to set the where param as string in `find/findOne` method in TypeORM?

Because, it seems that TypeORM doesn't accept private attributes as a param in `find/findOne` methods, and I understand why.

For example, this is the class used:

```
import { Column } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export default class Client extends BaseEntity{
    ...

    @Column({ name: 'email', type: 'varchar', length: 64, unique: true })
    private _email: string;

    ...
}
```

This is the controller function:

```
...

async function testing(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const { name, email, password } = request.body;
    
    const existingClient = await Client.findOne({ _email: email });

    console.log(existingClient);
}

...
```

I thought creating something like:

```
await Client.findOne({`email = testing@email.com`});
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This seems strange. Why would you want the field private here? Perhaps this open issue it relevant: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3548

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to simply use it as `public`.

When you really want to use `private`, you probably need to use the entitymanager:

```
entityManager
    .createQueryBuilder(Client, "client")
    .where("client._email = :email", { email: 'testing@email.com' })
    .getOne();
```

What is and how to add `entityManager`: https://typeorm.io/#/working-with-entity-manager

Comment: I think this is the best solution, thanks man! :D